# How do I open a Ghost local html file in which I want to run javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, ghost.py

How do I open a Ghost local html file in which I want to run javascript? I only know how to do it from a tutorial from the internet.

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, extra_resources = ghost.open(url)
```

Comment: is this your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the url provide the local location.

Example: `page, extra_resources = ghost.open('/home/dan/index.html')`

Comment: I think he did this but, he didn't want to show us where the file is located, for some reason??

Comment: page, extra_resources = ghost.open('url = 'file://localhost/home/dan/index.html') work